# Почему функция вывела такой результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
say('Вася');

var phrase = 'Привет';

function say(name) {
  alert( name + ", " + phrase );
}
```

Вот так другой результат почему ?

```js
var phrase = 'Привет';

function sayHi(name) {
  alert(phrase + ', ' + name);
}

sayHi('Вася');  // Привет, Вася (*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что *декларации* переменных перемещаются (are hoisted) в начало функций, а присвоения остаются там, где были.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

```js
var phrase;

// переменной phrase здесь еще не присвоено значение
say('Вася');

phrase = 'Привет';

function say(name) {
  console.log(name + ", " + phrase);
}
```

Comment: Проще говоря, в первом примере функция использует переменную, которая еще не **присвоилась :)**, так? :)

Comment: @entithat *не присвоилась* - существует, но не получила значение

Comment: @Igor я не знаю английский https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Comment: @xes Не проблема. В Хроме - нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на странице и выберите в меню "Перевести эту страницу".

Comment: @Igor как я понял в первом примере создается внутренний объект переменных  где аргумент равен "Вася" доходит до phrase равен undefined ищет через закрытую ссылку [[scope]] phrase  находит что что в объекте window она равна undefined b возвращает ее правильно ?

Comment: @Igor  написал до твоего примера

Comment: Выполнение скрипта происходит в  2 фазы. 1 фаза происходит инициализация где переменные и функции записываются в глобальный объект который доступен в браузере под именем window. переменные равны undefined; функции если они созданы как function declaration сразу работающими. 2 фаза происходит присваивания

Comment: @Igor say('Вася'); мы запускаем функцию где создается внутренний объект и закрытое свойство [[scope]] получается внутреннем объекте name = 'Вася' а phrase = undefined. благодаря [[scope]] ищет во внешнем объекте переменных находит что phrase = undefined (2 фаза не прозошла так присваивание идет после  и возвращает undefined) правильно ?

Comment: @ Igor компютерный перевод криво переводит же ли нет ?

Comment: @xes смысл же ясен

Comment: @Igor  ясно а я что написа  оно true ?

Comment: @xes да, хотя мое объяснение (первая строчка в ответе) мне нравится больше )

Comment: @Igor я свою портянку писал до того как увидел твой ответ(код)